# Setting multiple alarms in Android Studio with an alarmmanager causes problems

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I currently have a small project running in Android Studio that I need help with. I want to include a reminder function with notifications.
I have a total of 4 time pickers for each of which I want to set an alarm at the corresponding selected time.
With my current code the planned feature works only halfway, with the following problem:

If I select one time, then I sometimes get a notification at this time as desired. However, not always on time. Most of the time the alert doesn't appear and if it does, then half a minute to a minute later. And if I set all 4 alarms, in the best case I get a notification at the last selected time. In the worst case nothing happens.

But all I want is to get daily notifications at the selected 4 times.

About my code, I use an alarm manager which I call 4 times for the 4 alarms. I also use a broadcast receiver in which the notification is triggered. And I use a different `RequestCode` for each `PendingIntent`.

I really searched all relevant posts on SO, but not one of them worked for me. Maybe I have included it in the wrong way. I hope someone can help me. Here are my methods:

**Alarm method from Activity.class**
(UhrzeitInMillis describes the chosen time by timepicker, for example `16.03`):

```java
public void SetAlarm(Context context, long UhrzeitInMillis) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Optionen_Alarm.class);
    final int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), id, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, UhrzeitInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver (Optionen_Alarm.java):**

````java
public class Optionen_Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "myapp:mywakelocktag");
        wl.acquire();

        createNotificationChannel(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1");
        builder.setContentTitle("titel");
        builder.setContentText("text!");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.picture);
        builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 300, 300, 300});
        builder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 1000, 5000);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("text!"));

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notificationCompat = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        managerCompat.notify(15, notificationCompat);

        wl.release();


        private void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = "name";
                String description = "description";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", name, importance);
                channel.setDescription(description);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }

    }
```java
````

Answer (score 0):

For battery reason, from android 6.0 the time you set on the alarm manager will not be guaranteed to trigger at the exact same time you have set. You could use the method '''setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()''' to make the alarm behave like you want.
You can read more about this here https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms